# Jaybird (Firebird JDBC) ResultSet FetchSize -- Pagination long lasting queries

Tags: java, jdbc, pagination, firebird, jaybird

I am trying to find a way how to force jaybird to do "pagination" in ResultSet. Suppose we have some long lasting sql query (it returns for example 5000 rows in 15 seconds). However, fetching of first 50 (random) rows takes just a fraction of second. So long as we do not add order by clause to the query, the server quickly returns first rows, which can be immediately shown in the client application. This is btw the default behaviour of flamerobin client.

I try to simulate this behaviour with setting the Statement parameters like in the code below, but without success. Is there a way to force jaybird not to load all rows to the ResultSet? I suppose that the method stmt.setFetchSize(50) has this purpose but it is perhaps wrong. Jaybird version used was 2.2.7 and Firebird version used was 2.5.4. Thank you for your advices.

```
String user = "user";
String pass = "pass";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s, user, pass);
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(50);
stmt.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
ResultSet rs = null;
String sql = "select * from TABLE"; //long lasting select 
boolean ok = stmt.execute(sql);
if (ok) {
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
         //do something
    }
}
if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
}

if (stmt != null) {
    stmt.close();
}
```

I try to achieve same think as flamerobin client does -- on the fly load of the data to the table (only when we need them -- scroll down in the table). We develop application which is a client of two tier ERP system (DB server firebird, client on netbeans platform).We wrote some database components which fills JXTable with data on the same principle like "interbase Delphi components" did in the past. The code above is symplified, in the component code we load the first 100 rows to the JTable table model and when user scrolls down we load another 100 rows etc. However I notice that the load time of the first 100 rows is the same as if we load all rows to the dataset. That is the code

```
boolean ok = stmt.execute(sql);
if (ok) {
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    int rows = 0;
    while (rs.next() rows < 100) {
         //do something
         rows++;
    }
}
```

took practicaly same time as the  first chunk of source code. It seems, that the stmt.execute(sql) command waits until all select rows are returned from server. However I set that I want to get 50 rows chunks, so I supposed that the while cycle will start immediately after getting first 50 rows from the DB server. So I want start the while cycle after fetching first 50 rows (as if I set stmt.setMaxRows(50)), but I want to have oportunity to let the result set open and fetch another rows on demand.

Comment: Setting the fetch size will instruct jaybird to fetch rows in batches of 50 (although some Firebird versions may choose to return a smaller number). However it will not limit the number of rows returned. Your code is still fetching all rows, just in batches of 50. What is it you are trying to achieve? If you want to return only fifty initially, then you should not call next() more than fifty times, or use `setMaxRows`.

Comment: Question was appended (completed) as a reaction to Mark Rotteveel comment.

Comment: Are you using `defaultResultSetHoldable=true` in your connection string?

Comment: my connection url is jdbc:firebirdsql:server:/path/db.fdb?encoding=UTF8&dialect=3&defaultHoldable

Comment: If you use `defaultResultSetHoldable` the entire result set is retrieved immediately.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the clue!  
We use
    conn.setHoldability(ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
in our DB components. However, we did not set the
    stmt.setFetchSize(50)
in our DB component. Therefore default size 400 was used (and it took a lot of time to fetch). And in my small test case where I set correctly the fetch size I forgot to set the holdability of the connection to 
    ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT

Comment: Great! I will post a more detailed answer tomorrow. Note that the default is `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` unless you specify `default(ResultSet)Holdable`. Just not adding that connection property would be better if you normally don't need holdable result sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setFetchSize` normally does exactly what you expect: it will fetch rows in batches of the specified size (Firebird 3 can decide to return less when it considers the batch too big).

However as you have specified `defaultHoldable` in your connection string, the result set is `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`, and holdable result sets are fully cached client-side before they are returned.

You either need to set the holdability to `CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` for this specific statement, or - if you do this for all statements - just remove the `defaultHoldable` from your connection string.